# Pandas multi-index and stack from list of dataframes

Tags: python, database, pandas, stack

I have 3 lists, say A, B, & C that look like this:

```
A = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"]
B = ["location1", "location2", "location3"]
C = [pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 3), columns=list('ABC'))]*3
```

How do I create a multiindex dataframe with 3 levels of indexing, i.e. of A, B and the two indices (0 to 1) of C?

What I've tried so far is creating a dictionary with all the three indices by looping through all the 3 lists and the dataframe columns, and then, when I have to slice the data, again looping over the keys with a condition. This works but seems pretty inefficient as I have 10 million items in my dictionary. I was wondering if there was a one liner Pandas syntax for this using multiindex and stack. I saw the documentation for these, but the syntax is not clear to me yet. Am I missing any other Pandas function that can help with this? And should I use a database instead?

Comment: `pd.MultiIndex.from_product([A,B,C])`

Comment: Thanks, Wen! sorry, I edited the question a bit now. I said C was a list of lists earlier, but its actually a list of dataframes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:
[See my post on `pd.concat` for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49620539/2336654)
[Or the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)

```
pd.concat(C, keys=list(zip(A, B)), axis=1)

        Jan                           Feb                           Mar                    
  location1                     location2                     location3                    
          A         B         C         A         B         C         A         B         C
0 -0.519821 -1.820451 -0.645732 -0.519821 -1.820451 -0.645732 -0.519821 -1.820451 -0.645732
1  1.043477 -0.666565 -0.298504  1.043477 -0.666565 -0.298504  1.043477 -0.666565 -0.298504
```

---

Alternatively

```
pd.concat(dict(zip(zip(A, B), C)), axis=1)
```

Comment: Great, this solved it. And your post is pretty helpful too! Thanks for sharing!