# Add new level to MultiIndex when concatenating

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

A few data frames identical in size, columns and indices but varying a bit in content are concatenated. What would be the best way of generating a new index such that the original indices remain the same, but the outermost index now represents the data frame number that was concatenated?

```
DataFrame A:
Idx1 | Idx2 || Col
0      0       'A'
       1       'B'
1      0       'C'
       1       'D'

DataFrame B:
Idx1 | Idx2 || Col
0      0       'E'
       1       'F'
1      0       'G'
       1       'H'

DataFrame AB:
Idx0 | Idx1 | Idx2 || Col
0      0      0       'A'
              1       'B'
       1      0       'C'
              1       'D'
1      0      0       'E'
              1       'F'
       1      0       'G'
              1       'H'
```

I'm still not so comfortable with my indices and stacking, but I imagine that would be needed. Any help is greatly appreciated!

#### Sandbox:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'Idx1': [0,0,1,1], 'Idx2':[0,1,0,1]})
B = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'], 'Idx1': [0,0,1,1], 'Idx2':[0,1,0,1]})
A.set_index(keys=['Idx1', 'Idx2'], inplace=True)
B.set_index(keys=['Idx1', 'Idx2'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49620538/what-are-the-levels-keys-and-names-arguments-for-in-pandas-concat-functio/49620539#49620539

Comment: @Wen Thank you my friend, looks good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with the `keys` and `names` arguments:

```
pd.concat([A, B], keys=[0, 1], names=['Idx0'])
```

The resulting output:

```
               Col
Idx0 Idx1 Idx2    
0    0    0      A
          1      B
     1    0      C
          1      D
1    0    0      E
          1      F
     1    0      G
          1      H
```