# When is it smart to merge vs concat two pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

Suppose there are two dataframes that share the same index but have different columns. Is it smarter to merge the two dataframes here or concat?

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

df1 = DataFrame(index = ['hey', 'yo'], columns = ['gee', 'thanks'], data = [[1,'foo'],[6,'rhy']]) 
df2 = DataFrame(index = ['hey', 'yo'], columns = ['youre', 'welcome'], data = [[8,'fotb'],[3,'yuo']])

#using merging
df3_merge = df1.merge(df2,left_index = True, right_index = True)  

#result:      
#             gee  thanks  youre  welcome
# hey          1    foo      8    fotb
# yo           6    rhy      3     yuo

#using concatenate
df3_concat = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis = 1)  

#result:      
#             gee  thanks  youre  welcome
# hey          1    foo      8    fotb
# yo           6    rhy      3     yuo
```

[This link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) inspired this question. Typically I have always used `concat`, but I am curious to what others use or think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends, what need.

By default, in [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) is `inner` join, but is possible change it to `outer`, `right` or `left`.

```
df3_merge = df1.merge(df2,left_index = True, right_index = True)
```

Be default in [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) is outer join, but is possible change it to `inner` only by `inner` parameter:

```
df3_concat = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis = 1)
```

Also if want join list of DataFrames, simplier and faster is `concat` method.

If want left join, `concat` cannot be used, because not implemented.

---

More information about [`concat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49620538/what-are-the-levels-keys-and-names-arguments-for-in-pandas-concat-functio/49620539#49620539).

More information about [`merge`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101).