# How to combine two rows of same dataset side by side in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset and I want to combine the first two rows of the same dataset into a single dataset. The original dataset is very big but I have mentioned a small example here.

```
df

  one  two  three
0  T    H     A
1  N    K     S
2  F    O     R
3  H    L     P
```

After combining the first two rows it should look like this:

```
df

  one  two  three  one  two  three
0  T    H     A     N    K     S
```

I'm very new to StackOverflow and started my career recently in python. If my question is not formatted correctly please suggest edits. Thanks.

Comment: Please place the question in the actual body of your post. It makes it easier for users to actually understand what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `df.iloc` to get two slices of the dataframe one for even rows and another for odd rows. Then `pd.concat(..., axis=1)` to get them back together.

Notice `pd.concat` will try to align the input dataframes on their index (i.e. `0, 1, 2, 3`) and if one of the dataframes does not have data for a particular index then it will fill with null values. So we need `reset_index` to get the desired output.

```
df = pd.concat(
    [
        df.iloc[::2].reset_index(drop=True),
        df.iloc[1::2].reset_index(drop=True)
    ], axis=1
)
```

Output

```
  one two three one two three
0   T   H     A   N   K     S
1   F   O     R   H   L     P
```

You can read more about `pd.concat` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49620539/6692898) and of course [the user guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49620539/6692898)