# Guide on understanding documentation of a function in Python

Tags: python

Is there a guide/instruction on how to read and understand a Python's documentation? As an example, `help(pd.concat)` produces the following text

```
concat(objs: Union[Iterable[Union[ForwardRef('DataFrame'), ForwardRef('Series')]], Mapping[Union[Hashable, NoneType], Union[ForwardRef('DataFrame'), ForwardRef('Series')]]], axis=0, join='outer', ignore_index: bool = False, keys=None, levels=None, names=None, verify_integrity: bool = False, sort: bool = False, copy: bool = True) -> Union[ForwardRef('DataFrame'), ForwardRef('Series')]
...
keys : sequence, default None
        If multiple levels passed, should contain tuples. Construct
        hierarchical index using the passed keys as the outermost level.
levels : list of sequences, default None
        Specific levels (unique values) to use for constructing a
        MultiIndex. Otherwise they will be inferred from the keys.
```

I had no ideas what it meant by `keys` and `levels` in the help documentation. Is the (specific) **levels** (in `levels`) the same as (multiple) **levels** (in `keys`)? Is the help documentation only meant for developers? Is there a dictionary/indexes for the arguments? Why can't the help documentation of a function have an example for each of its arguments?

Answer (score 1):

for this kind of function. better read the documentation instead of doc. the doc is a concise summary due to space limit.

you may need the documentations, such as [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas-concat)

Comment: Thanks, Tomy. The documentation is almost the same as the help doc. Although there were examples for `keys`, none for `levels`!

Comment: if you are just looking for `pd.concat`. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49620539/13837927) may help u  :)

Comment: I just used `pd.concat` as an example. A lot of time when reading either help or documentation, I couldn't follow the *explanation* for some arguments of the functions