# Map two dataframes with Common columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have two dataframes with n number of common columns. There are 48 columns in the first and 56 columns in the other one. I'm trying to concat these columns vertically using pd.concat and I'm always getting the following error ***Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects***.

df1

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c |

df2

| Column 1 | Column 3 | Column 2 | Column 5 | Column 6 | Column 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | a | Nan | c |

I want to concat this vertically.
But I get the following error ***Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects***.

```
Merged_Data = pd.concat([Merged_Data,df] , join = "outer", ignore_index = True).reset_index(drop = True)
```

It's a huge dataframe and can't share it due to security reasons.
I believe the problem lies in the column indexing but I have tried a lot of things

Comment: Can you post the code, that's returning the error you mentioned?

Comment: There are [many ways to use `concat`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49620538/2336654).  I would like to see the dataframes with the index intact and the actual `concat` statement you are using.

Answer (score 0):

What if you just use

`pd.concat([df1, df2])`

without the index or reset_index parts?

Comment: Tried all this. Doesn't work for some reason.