# Python Concat two dataframe after grouping and sort

Tags: python, pandas

i have two pandas frame and i want to get one

```
     asks_price  asks_qty exchange_name_ask
0      20156.51  0.000745          Coinbase
1      20156.52  0.050000          Coinbase
```

```
     bids_price  bids_qty exchange_name_bid
2      20153.28  0.000200          Coinbase
3      20153.27  0.051000          Coinbase
```

Get ====>

```
     asks_price  asks_qty exchange_name_ask     bids_price  bids_qty exchange_name_bid
0      20156.51  0.000745          Coinbase      20153.28  0.000200          Coinbase
1      20156.52  0.050000          Coinbase      20153.27  0.051000          Coinbase
```

```
ask_snapshot = ask_snapshot.groupby('asks_price')['asks_qty'].sum().reset_index()
bid_snapshot = bid_snapshot.groupby('bids_price')['bids_qty'].sum().reset_index()
ask_snapshot = ask_snapshot.sort_values(by='asks_price').reset_index()
bid_snapshot = bid_snapshot.sort_values(by='bids_price', ascending=False).reset_index()
ask = ask_snapshot.head(20)
bid = bid_snapshot.head(20)

snapshot = pd.concat([ask, bid], axis=1, join='inner')
```

in the snapshot the exchange_name column disappear, i dont know why
Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) work for you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the 'levels', 'keys', and names arguments for in Pandas' concat function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49620538/what-are-the-levels-keys-and-names-arguments-for-in-pandas-concat-functio)

Comment: No i already try pandas.concat it doent work

Comment: this is the most basic standard textbook concat which in every single tutorial is explained. concat to dataframes together along axis=1. what do you mean by right index ? both of your dataframes have the same index

Comment: No in my exemple they have the same but not always              . When i am trying to reset index before concat , the exchange name dissapear

Comment: In your desired output is the left index...you said you want to have the right index? I guess you forgot to edit that too.

Comment: Do you know a solution thanks

Comment: How about you take a minute and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly. We aren't here to guess what you maybe want or don't want. Change your question with accurate input and desired output and you will get the right answer in no time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two columns `exchange_name..` doesn't disappear when you use [**`pandas.concat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) but they simply doesn't exist in the two dataframes passed as arguments.

Try this :

```
ask_snapshot = ask_snapshot.groupby(['asks_price', 'exchange_name_ask'], as_index=False)['asks_qty'].sum()
bid_snapshot = bid_snapshot.groupby(['bids_price', 'exchange_name_bid'], as_index=False)['bids_qty'].sum()
ask_snapshot = ask_snapshot.sort_values(by='asks_price').reset_index()
bid_snapshot = bid_snapshot.sort_values(by='bids_price', ascending=False).reset_index()
ask = ask_snapshot.head(20)
bid = bid_snapshot.head(20)

snapshot = pd.concat([ask, bid], axis=1)
```

Comment: hey , i have a question . i want to do the same things 
but without moving the columns

Comment: it works but it changes the order of my columns

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```py
snapshot = pd.concat([ask_snapshot.reset_index(drop=True),
    bid_snapshot.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```

Comment: it doesn t work..

Comment: It add new column level_0

Comment: @Nathan Yeah I forgot sorry

Comment: @Nathan Try this one. Make sure you have replaced the whole code. You don't really need those groupby's lol

Comment: No yet .. maybe because the grouping or the sort i dont know

Comment: The exchange name disappear before i think but i dont know why